# how to solve the error 'Passwords must be at least eight characters and match the confirmation.' in laravel 5.8

Tags: laravel, email, reset-password

when i type the email and the password and i click on reset password , if the password is less then 3 characters it shows an error saying password must be at least 3 characters, but if i type a password of more then 3 characters , it shows an error in email input saying Passwords must be at least eight characters and match the confirmation, and the password is confirmed and matches the confiramtion.

rules method in the resetPasswordController.php :

```
protected function rules()
{
    return [
        'token' => 'required',
        'email' => 'required|email',
        'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:3',
    ];
}
```

and how do i solve this problem to reset the password succefully without showing Passwords must be at least eight characters and match the confirmation?

Comment: did you check you have reached same function you want to ?

Comment: yes in the /vendor the rules function is defining ythe validation, and if i change the min to min:4 it works

Answer (score 4):

Just add `rules()` method, in the Auth\ResetPasswordsController.php after `construct()`:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
      'password' => ['required', 'min:5', 'confirmed']

    ];
}
```

Here's the screenshot, [click me.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qk4Y.png)

And, please, keep in mind, never edit vendor/ files.

Comment: Great, this is the best solution i've found.

Answer (score 2):

It's hardcoded in laravel 5.8. To fix it you will need to override some of the classes.

**1.) Create a CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider inside App\Providers**

You need to create a new `CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider` class which we will use to replace the Default `PasswordResetServiceProvider`

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Services\CustomPasswordBrokerManager;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    protected $defer = true;

    public function register()
    {
        $this->registerPasswordBrokerManager();
    }

    public function provides()
    {
        return ['auth.password'];
    }

    protected function registerPasswordBrokerManager()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('auth.password', function ($app) {
            return new CustomPasswordBrokerManager($app);
        });
    }
}
```

**2.) Replace Service Provider in app/config.php**

Next, we need to replace the newly created ServiceProvider in our app/config.php

Open you app/config.php file and comment out PasswordResetServiceProvider and add new the ServiceProvider class.

```
//Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordResetServiceProvider::class,

App\Providers\CustomPasswordResetServiceProvider::class,
```

**3.) Create new CustomPasswordBrokerManager class**

Create a new class CustomPasswordBrokerManager and under directory App/Services and copy all the contents of **PasswordBrokerManager**  which is located at `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBrokerManager.php`

Then modified the function **resolve** to return an instance of my **CustomPasswordProvider** class

```
    protected function resolve($name)
    {
        $config = $this->getConfig($name);

        if (is_null($config)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("Password resetter [{$name}] is not defined.");
        }

        return new CustomPasswordBroker(
            $this->createTokenRepository($config),
            $this->app['auth']->createUserProvider($config['provider'] ?? null)
        );
    }
```

**4. Create CustomPasswordBroker**

Finally, You can now create your new CustomPasswordBroker class under App/Services directory which extends the default PasswordBroker class located at `Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker`

```
<?php

namespace App\Services;

use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker as BasePasswordBroker;

class CustomPasswordBroker extends BasePasswordBroker
{
    /**
     * Determine if the passwords are valid for the request.
     *
     * @param array $credentials
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function validatePasswordWithDefaults(array $credentials)
    {
        $minPassLength = 6;

        [$password, $confirm] = [
            $credentials['password'],
            $credentials['password_confirmation'],
        ];

        return $password === $confirm && mb_strlen($password) >= $minPassLength;
    }
}
```

Now, you can override the functions that you need. Mostly you will need to start your modification with function `sendResetLink` and then you can take it ahead from there.

credit: https://www.5balloons.info/extending-passwordbroker-class-laravel-5/

Answer (score 2):

I found simple and short resolve this problem here [PasswordBroker has a hard-coded minimum password length of 8 characters (overriding ResetsPasswords::rules() has no effect)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/28274#issuecomment-517008973)

Theкe you can found reason why it be maked.

Comment: for those who seek the write answer for fixing hardcoded password validation this solution is best and requires minimum effort and its clean way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

you can overwrite method  of validator like below.

```
/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:3', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you everyone the solution was :

What you are looking for is in this class:

\Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\PasswordBroker
and this function

validatePasswordWithDefaults
This looks a little weird that 8 is hardcoded in this function. I guess there is probably better practice for changing that. Maybe you could over-ride the function in your controller. Try that as well.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 10
In `./app/Http/Controllers/Auth/PasswordController.php`

```
class PasswordController extends Controller
{
  /**
   * Update the user's password.
   */
  public function update(Request $request): RedirectResponse
  {
    $validated = $request->validateWithBag('updatePassword', [
      'current_password' => ['required', 'current_password'],
      'password'         => ['required', 'min:2', 'confirmed'], // Here! instead of Password::defaults()
    ]);
```